# Padding to the left and right of a floated image, in IE only

Tags: internet-explorer

Generally I seem to be able to fix IE problems nowadays.. but this one realy has me stuck!

Take a look at the screenshot below to see the problem or visit the url to see the problem.

http://homedynamics.com/sawgrass/floorplan.php

[alt text http://homedynamics.com/sawgrass/images/models/i_hate_ie.jpg](http://homedynamics.com/sawgrass/images/models/i_hate_ie.jpg)

I have made sure the ul li and img's are all cleared (padding:0; margin:0; border:0;) and still there is padding added to the left and right of the images.  I also did "display: block" on images with no luck.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?   Thanks!!

Comment: main problem here .. is that i am only helping with this site. by no means did i design this site or develop the core html.  i was asked to add stuff. and its horendous.. tables.. none validating code :(  my portion is good.. but still..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set margin padding float to divs containing images.